# How can I return an array of elements, instead of a single one, in a Rails JSON API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have this line of code

```
render json: { message: t(:incorrect_password) }, status: :unauthorized
```

which results in this response...

```
{
    "message": "Please re-enter your password. The password entered is incorrect."
}
```

but I want the response to look like this...

```
{
    "message": [
        "Please re-enter your password. The password entered is incorrect."
    ]
}
```

What is the proper way to achieve this, returning the result as the element of an array, instead of as a single entity?

Comment: did you try `render json: { message: [t(:incorrect_password)] }, status: :unauthorized`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the above comment suggests, you can simply wrap an array literal around the message, like so...

```
render json: { message: [t(:incorrect_password)] }, status: :unauthorized
```

Or, you can call wrap it with a call to `Array`, like this...

```
render json: { message: Array(t(:incorrect_password)) }, status: :unauthorized
```